# FileNotFoundException when importing resource in different assembly and base folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to import an .xaml file from another package, that is in a different folder. I am using the "pack-import" but I get an XamlParseException when I try to run code using this, which wraps a FileNotFoundException with the message "Could not load file or assembly 'Project.UI, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Import (in ScreenView.xaml):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Project.UI;component/Themes/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

File structure:
Importing file:
Project/**specific**/client/Project.Module/Views/Screen/ScreenView.xaml
Imported file:
Project/**common**/client/Project.UI/Themes/generic.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 reasont this error may be happening:

1. Your SPECIFIC project doesn't reference the COMMON project (which gives the FileNotFoundException as inner exception exactly as you described)
2. Project.UI is not an assembly name of your COMMON project